# What state does the particle in a box occupy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hilbert-space, potential

My textbook derives the equations for the different energy states $E_n$ of the [particle in a box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box). But my professor in class said this example was a good one because it spoke about the "superposition of states".

I'm not seeing how there can be any superposition of states. I know differential equations allow for a superposition of solutions, but not in this case, because each solution $\Psi$ needs of a specific value of $E$.

What am I getting wrong here? If there is a superposition of states, how does it happen in a mathematical way? How would you calculate the probability of it being in a certain state? How can you know its in state, e.g., $n=1$.

Comment: "...each solution $\Psi$ needs of a specific value of $E$." This is not the case. I think you're confusing the time-dependent Schrödinger equation ($i \hbar \partial_t \Psi(\mathbf{x}, t) = H \Psi(\mathbf{x}, t)$) with the time-*in*dependent Schrödinger equation ($H \psi_n(\mathbf{x}) = E_n \psi_n(\mathbf{x})$). It's the former that a wavefunction $\Psi(\mathbf{x}, t)$ needs to satisfy in general; the latter only gives you the stationary states of a system.

Comment: Oooohhh, you have caught my mistake. I think that clears things up.

Comment: Hey, but then the rule for norm=1 applies to the individuals components of $\Psi_{total}$ and not the whole one? I have been normalising each $\psi_n$, wouldn't this be against the Born rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenstates aren't the only allowed physical states. It's a postulate of quantum mechanics that the most general quantum state can be written as a superposition of eigenstates of some operator (the Hamiltonian for instance). For instance $\Psi(x)=\sum_nc_n\psi_n(x)$ is a general quantum state for a particle in a box, where $\psi_n(x)$ are the energy eigenstates. The probability of measuring an energy $E_n$ is simply $|c_n|^2$. If a particle exists in an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian however, you will always measure the same energy.

Comment: Each eigenstate satisfies its own version of the Schrödinger equation then? Where each version has its own $E$?

Comment: The eigenstates actually satisfy the time independent Schrodinger equation, one for each energy E. The time independent Schrodinger equation is actually just the eigen-equation for the energy, i.e $\hat{H}\psi_n=E_n\psi_n$. Every observable (Hermitian) operator has an eigen-equation, and the eigenvalues are the only allowed possible outcomes of a measurement.

Comment: The time dependent equation ultimately tells you how a generic quantum state $\Psi$ evolves in time in the presence of a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is the very essence of the QM. In short, **when we observe a superposed state, the probability of observing specific eigenvalue is the *square of the norm of the corresponding eigenstate* in the superposed state.** And this is more like a *postulate*, rather than a mathematical derivation.

For example, particle in a box has discrete eigenvalues, bounded below. So, we can denote $n$-th eigenstate as $|n\rangle $, who satisfies $\hat{H}|n\rangle=E_n |n\rangle$.

Let $e_n=E_n/E_1$ be normalized eigenvalue. It can be shown that for this case, $e_n=n^2$. 
Let $\hat{h}=\hat{H}/E_1$ be the normalized hamiltonian.

A particle at $|1\rangle$ would have $e_1=1$. State $|2\rangle$ would correspond to $e_2=4$. 
But particle does not necessarily have its energy one of these discrete states. They are just *eigen*states, which is special set of solutions for given DE.

Consider a particle, who has normalized energy of $e=2$. What state should this particle correspond to? (these states do exist, despite they are not one of the eigenstate.)

One of the answer could be 
$$
\left|\psi\right\rangle = \left. \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\middle|1 \right\rangle + \left. \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\middle|2 \right\rangle
$$
Why?

Expected energy value is calculated by $e=\langle \psi| \hat{h}|\psi\rangle$, and for this case,
$$
e= \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\middle\langle 1 \middle| + \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\middle\langle 2 \middle | \right ) \hat{h} \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\middle|1 \right\rangle + \left. \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\middle|2 \middle\rangle \right)\\
=\frac{2}{3}e_1 + \frac{1}{3}e_2 = \frac{2}{3}+ \frac{1}{3}\times 4\\
=2
$$

Then, what happens when we observe energy?

Even though we *have* a state that is not an eigenstate, **we cannot measure the energy other than the eigenvalue of the hamiltonian**, which is one of the *postulates of the quantum mechanics*. So, either $e=1$ or $e=4$ would be observed.

**The probability of finding any state in $n$-th eigenstate is the square of the coefficient of the state $|n\rangle$ for the given superposed state**, which is also one of the *postulates of the quantum mechanics*. Thus, finding $e=1$ is $2/3$, while probability of finding $e=4$ is $1/3$.

Wait. Then what happens to the energy conservation? This is why the Quantum Mechanics is *weird*. In the process of observation, the energy does not necessarily conserved, along with other observables--mostly conserved variables, such as angular momentum. As long as the energy expectation value does not change over time *without observation*, the energy is considered to be conserved.

While writing this, I referred to Shankar's *the Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, chapter 4. Since you study QM this semester, I think you should fully understand this to understand QM itself.